# Reactjs and 2 elements animations at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to implementing this effect with Reactjs. bellow youtube video is the animation I'm trying to implement :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVBAMiu1NPE&feature=youtu.be

Now I need to make them into a Reactjs component, I am using react-addons-css-transition-group. what my code should do is everytime I press a button, that will render a div paragraph in the tabContent array, which then should be animated by ReactCSSTransitionGroup. This is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: 0
    };

    this.active = {
      color: '#4286f4',
      outline: 'none'
    };
    this.inactive = {};
  }


  customChange(tabNum) {
    this.setState({
      activeTab: tabNum
    });
  };

render() {
        var tabContent = [<div>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                          nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                          </div>,
                          <div>
                          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                          eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident
                          </div>,
                          <div>
                          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                          doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
                          veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                          </div>,
                          <div>
                          Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
                          sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                          </div>
                        ]
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid mainDiv'>
                <div id='TabsNav'>
                    <button style={this.state.activeTab === 0 ? this.active : this.inactive} onClick={() => {this.customChange(0)}} className='roundBorderLeft InfoButton'> <br/> btn1 </button>
                    <button style={this.state.activeTab === 1 ? this.active : this.inactive} onClick={() => {this.customChange(1)}} className='adjustLeft InfoButton'> <br/> btn2</button>
                    <button style={this.state.activeTab === 2 ? this.active : this.inactive} onClick={() => {this.customChange(2)}} className='adjustLeft InfoButton'> <br/> btn3</button>
                    <button style={this.state.activeTab === 3 ? this.active : this.inactive} onClick={() => {this.customChange(3)}} className='adjustLeft roundBorderRight InfoButton'>  <br/> btn4</button>
                </div>
                <div id='TabContents'>
                  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName='tab' transitionEnterTimeout={2000} transitionLeaveTimeout={2000}>
                      {tabContent[this.state.activeTab]}
                  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
```

this is part of my css i used for transition:

```
.tab-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, padding-left 2s;
}

.tab-enter.tab-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.tab-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, padding-left 2s;
}

.tab-leave.tab-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 200px;
}


.mainDiv {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;

}
```

My code shown no animation, the tab's content appears instantly without any animation. what did i do wrong?

Comment: video is not working

Comment: it's working now, had it in private mode, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres a way to achieve what you want :

JS

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            activeTab: 0,
            previousTab: -1
        };
    },
    customChange: function (tabNum) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: tabNum,
            previousTab: this.state.activeTab
        });
    },

    buildButton: function (content, index) {
        return (
            <button 
                key={index}
                className={"button" + (index === this.state.activeTab ? " active" : "")} 
                onClick={() => {this.customChange(index)}}>
                btn{index + 1}
            </button>
        )
    },

    buildContent: function (content, index) {
        let clazz = "item"
        clazz += (index === this.state.activeTab ? " active" : "")
        clazz += (index === this.state.previousTab ? " inactive" : "")
        return (
            <div
                key={index}
                className={clazz}>
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    },

    render: function() {
        var tabContent = [
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident",
            "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.",
            "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt."
        ]
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid mainDiv'>
                <div className="buttons">
                    {tabContent.map(this.buildButton)}
                </div>
                <div className='content'>
                    {tabContent.map(this.buildContent)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

CSS

```
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons .button {
  outline: none;
  color: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
}

.buttons .button.active {
  color: black;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.item.active {
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.item.inactive {
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-15px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {        
        transform: translateX(15px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what you did here please? I am new to reactjs

Comment: I have no knowledge of ReactCSSTransitionGroup so I cant really tell you why yours was failing :p

Comment: @dg2903 you missed "key" attribute in tabcontents div. check my answer for details.

Comment: thank you so much. I have question, i notice in the .item in your css you set opacity to 0. Without that all the text would show up at the same time even when they are inactive, why is that?

Comment: opacity 0 is the default value, actually 'inactive' should be called 'fading out', it is only a temporary state (then the inactive class is removed)

Answer (score 1):

I checked it locally, you missed only one thing. Your code will work if you assign 'key' to your tabcontent div elements.  You must provide the key attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed. Check [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup).

```
var tabContent = [<div key="0">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                          nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                          </div>,
                          <div key="1">
                          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                          eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident
                          </div>,
                          <div key="2">
                          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                          doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
                          veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                          </div>,
                          <div key="3">
                          Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
                          sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                          </div>
                        ]
```

The css you have provided you will need to modify it for the result you want. Apart from that this 'key' will do the trick.

Comment: @dg2903 If the answer did help or was informative to the question at hand, please consider accepting/upvoting it.